# Ubuntu 20.04 virus/worm how can I remove?

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, android, configuration, remote-desktop

how do i remove a virus / worm from my ubuntu? although rare, i got infected and i can't remove it.

This virus infected my smartphone(android) and Smart TV(samsung) and through them the virus keeps coming back forever.